# How to plot a radar plot in R like the one in excel for the same data frame

Tags: r, excel, plot, radar-chart

I have this data frame made in R :

```
            Technical Junior  Entry-Level  Product Owner Technical Leader  Senior
Professional    2,236          3,581          3,781        3,654            4,454
Communication   2,619          3,333          4,285        4,190            4,952
Innovation      3,625          4,208          4,500        4,000            4,791
```

And I want to plot something like that in R (I have made this in Excel)

Radar plot made in excel

[image]

Please help me to make this graph through R cause I failed making it with `ggplot`, `ggtern`, `plotrix` and other libraries I cannot manage properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it very easily using `fmsb::radarchart()`. Note I had to remove the commas first from your data, which I then read in as `df`. I also had to add rows for the min and max to reproduce your Excel plot.

```
library(fmsb)
df1 <- data.frame(t(df))
dfminmax <- rbind(rep(max(df1), 3) , rep(min(df1), 3) , df1)
radarchart(dfminmax)
```

[image]

You're going to want to tweak the settings to make it look better. Use `?radarchart` to find out all the options.